# Event function declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Im trying to understand the declaration of the event handler and the function declaration in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46418688/7727532

Im pretty new to Javascript and jQuery and trying to understand. What I do know is that you declare like the following

```
$('#clickMe').on('click', doSomeThing(e));

function doSomeThing(e){
 console.log(e);
}
```

The first part I dont understand is

```
(e) => this._handleScaling(e)
```

What is happening here? We catch the current object and sending it to function _handleScaling()? But why do we have "(e) =>" before?

Second part is

```
_handleScaling(e) {
```

Which if Im right is a local function inside another? Because of the underline start. So maybe the code in the link isnt telling the whole picture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Comment: `$('#clickMe').on('click', doSomeThing(e));` is wrong. It calls `doSomeThing` immediately and passes its return value to `.on`. Whenever you have "pass" a function *call* as argument to another function (`foo(bar())`, the "inner" function call is evaluated first and its return value is passed to the "outer" call. I.e. `bar` is called first and its return value is passed to `foo`. Event handlers however expect a function to be passed.

Comment: Related: [What's the meaning of “=>” (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24900875/218196)

Comment: this is actually typescript syntax, and doesn't add anything to event handling itself. You're not obliged to use typescript for this, you can stick to basic JS if you know it. Just my opinion, but typescript adds more confusion than actual real improvements, if you already know well the prototype nature.

Comment: @Kaddath not exactly, [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are also a part of ES6

Comment: Thanks for the comments it clarifies a lot!

Comment: @SurajRao you're right, i should have a deeper look at it, however, i found no real use case where i could need arrow functions instead of regular ones yet..

Comment: @Kaddath alright :D maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939130/when-should-i-use-arrow-functions-in-ecmascript-6 is the right link for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give **function reference** rather than **function's return value**

Replace

```
$('#clickMe').on('click', doSomeThing(e));
```

with

```
$('#clickMe').on('click', doSomeThing); //e is the event object will be automatically passed on to the event handler
```

> The first part I dont understand is
>
> `(e) => this._handleScaling(e)` What is happening here? We catch the
>   current object and sending it to function `_handleScaling()`? But why do
>   we have `"(e) =>"` before?

No, **_handleScaling** is only passed `e` (event object) so that it can get access to element on which this `event` has been triggered using `e.target` since with *arrow function* `this` will refer to scope in which this *arrow function* is defined.